# How draw Hyperboloids with OpenGL C++?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw quadrics in C ++ with OpenGL.

Quadrics are the Sphere, and [Hyperboloides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid) of a leaf and two leaves. To draw them I use only the **parametric equations** of each. The sphere if I drew

**Example:** The parametric equations of the Sphere are:

[image: Sphere]

To draw the sphere with these equations, what I do in OpenGL is simply this for a sphere that is draw on the origin `x0`, `y0` and `z0` equal to zero:

```
void Sphere(){
    GLfloat x, y, z, alpha, beta; // Storage for coordinates and angles
    GLfloat radius = 1.0f;
    int gradation = 20;
    glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
    for (float alpha = 0.0; alpha < PI; alpha += PI/gradation)
    {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for (beta = 0.0; beta < 2.01*PI; beta += PI/gradation)
        {
            x = radius*cos(beta)*sin(alpha);
            y = radius*sin(beta)*sin(alpha);
            z = radius*cos(alpha);
            glVertex3f(x, y, z);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I the **result** is this (a sphere):

[image]

**Problem:**

By applying the same logic to the draw **hyperboloids**, I do not get what I want. The **parametric equations** of the Hyperboloides are as follows:

[image]

When attempting to draw the **hyperboloid** of one sheet with the equations shown in the **picture**, this is the result:

[image]

If anyone knows anything about it, please if you can help me with this. Thank you all.

**Note:** I know there are other ways to draw a hyperboloid, but the way I draw them is through its parametric equations.

Answer (score 0):

What is the code that produces this output, not the code that produces your sphere?  Please provide a MCVE.

Here is my guess: the range of your loops produces only positive values of *z*, and you might try the range `-PI` to `PI` instead.

Comment: The code of the sphere is that, only this rotated 45 degrees relative to axis Y

Comment: @L.Flor I’m afraid I don’t understand.  Can you provide a MCVE that generates the buggy output?

Comment: @L.Flor if you want help, provide [example code with how to build and everything](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) aka "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example".